# Rails Inheritance with relationships problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, inheritance

I am using single table inheritance in my project. Instead of explaining more, I'll give the code:

```
# person_profile.rb
class PersonProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Person
end

# company_profile.rb
class CompanyProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Company
end

# person.rb
class Person < User
  has_one :PersonProfile
end

# company.rb
class Company < User
  has_one :CompanyProfile
end
```

This seems to me like it should work fine. In one of my views I try `if @person.PersonProfile == nil` which makes perfect sense to me. But Rails doesn't like it:

```
 Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'person_profiles.person_id' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `person_profiles` WHERE (`person_profiles`.person_id = 41)  LIMIT 1
```

Rails is looking for person_id in the table person_profiles, but there is only a user_id in that table. What is the best way to fix this bug?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `:foreign_key` option of `has_one` to specify the key.

For example:

```
has_one :person, :foreign_key => "user_id"
```

See [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001791) reference.

Answer (score 2):

The models specified in your model associations should be in lowercase with each word being separated by an underscore. So:

```
class PersonProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end

class CompanyProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Person < User
  has_one :person_profile
end

class Company < User
  has_one :company_profile
end
```

Comment: thats true, then i guess i would say `@person.person_profile == nil`. But that still doesnt fix the problem. I get the same mysql error.

Answer (score 0):

i had to specify the foreign_key as 'user_id' because it thinks its 'person_id' by default.

```
class Person < User
   has_one :person_profile, :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end

class Company < User
   has_one :company_profile, :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end
```